# Получить данные с сайта с помощью js

Tags: javascript, chrome-extension

Приветствую. 
Есть в php функция - file_get_contents, которая читает содержимое файла в строку, которую можно дальше где-то использовать.

Вопрос: как сделать такое же, только с помощью js? Пробовал разные варианты и у меня не получилось. 
Это для расширения для хрома.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28858027/how-to-read-file-from-chrome-extension

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/597907/open-webpage-and-parse-it-using-javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем для того, чтобы получить данные из другого сайта в свое расширение я использовал `<iframe></iframe>` и мне этого хватило.

Answer (score 0):

Для получения данных с другого сайта можно использовать кросс доменные запросы:

```js
var XHR = ("onload" in new XMLHttpRequest()) ? XMLHttpRequest : XDomainRequest;

var xhr = new XHR();

xhr.open('GET', 'http://anywhere.com/request', true);

xhr.onload = function() {
  alert( this.responseText );
}

xhr.onerror = function() {
  alert( 'Error ' + this.status );
}

xhr.send();
```